# JS Button dosn't work after js DIV reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I hope that I have formulated title right. I'm newbie in programming and are struggling with problem.

I am trying to build my own E-commerce shopping cart(JS,PHP,HTML). Everything is working fine(add items, show items and everything else **except deleting order from cart**.)

Problem right now:
I can't delete order from shopping cart.(If I click button, nothing happens) But if I refresh/reload page. It works fine. But I want to delete it without reloading page. Using only ajax/js.

I think It might be because I am reloading shopping cart div when I add new Item, is it possible, that problem there?

I don't know how much code, do you need. I will try to give most important.

```
<!-- Shopping Cart MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade shoppingCartModal" id="shoppingCartModal" class="modal" style="margin-top:40px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="background-image: url('/Web/Images/ACP/background.gif');">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="container">
                <?php $shop->shoppingCart(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF Shopping Cart MODAL -->
```

Here's shoppingCart function:

```
public function shoppingCart(){
    try{

        $session_id = session_id();

        ?>
        <table id="cart" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:50%">Product</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Price</th>
            <th style="width:8%">Quantity</th>
            <th style="width:22%" class="text-center">Subtotal</th>
            <th style="width:10%"></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM shop_shoppingcart WHERE session_id='$session_id'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        $total = 0;

        foreach ($result as $order){

            $item_id = $order['item_id'];

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM shop_items WHERE id='$item_id'");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

            foreach ($result as $item){
            ?>
        <tbody id="cart_item_<?php echo $item['id']; ?>">
            <tr>
                <td data-th="Product">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs"><img src="../Web/<?php echo $order['item_image']; ?>" alt="..." class="img-responsive"/></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <h4 class="nomargin"><?php echo $order['item_name']; ?></h4>
                            <p>Color: <?php echo $order['item_color']; ?></br> Size: <?php echo $order['item_size']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td data-th="Price">
                    <?php if($item['saleprice'] > 0.00){
                        ?><span style="color:green"><?php echo $item['saleprice']; ?></span></br><?php
                        ?><s><span style="color:red"><?php echo $item['price']; ?></span></s></br><?php
                    }else{
                        ?><span style="color:green"><?php echo $item['price']; ?></span></br><?php
                    } ?></td>
                <td data-th="Quantity">
                    <p style="text-align:center"><?php echo $order['item_quantity']; ?></p>
                </td>
                <?php $itemTotal = $order['item_price'] * $order['item_quantity']; ?>
                <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center"><?php echo $itemTotal; ?></td>
                <td class="actions" data-th="">
                    <button id="delete_order_<?php echo $order['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                </td>
                <?php $total += $itemTotal; ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#delete_order_<?php echo $order['id']; ?>").click(function(){
                    $.ajax(
                        { url: "Shop.php?delete_item=true?action=select&id=<?php echo $order['id'];?>",
                            type: "get",
                            success: function(result){
                                document.getElementById('cart_item_<?php echo $item['id']; ?>').style.display = 'none';
                                $('#cart_total').load(document.URL +  ' #cart_total');
                                $('#navigation').load(document.URL +  ' #navigation');
                            }
                        });
                    });

            });
        </script>

        <?php } } ?>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="continueShopping()" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Continue Shopping</a></td>
                <td colspan="2" class="hidden-xs"></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs text-center"><strong id="cart_total">Total: <?php echo $total; ?></strong></td>
                <?php if($total > 0.00){ ?><td><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="cart_checkout">Checkout <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></td><?php } ?>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <script>
        var shoppingCartModal = document.getElementById('shoppingCartModal');

        function continueShopping(){
            $(shoppingCartModal).modal('hide');
        }
    </script>

    <?php
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

> Button that don't work, If I don't refresh page.

```
<button id="delete_order_<?php echo $order['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
```

And possibly this might be code, why it won't work!? (Script that refreshes shoppingCartModal when new item added)

```
    <script>
        function AddToCart_<?php echo $item['id'];?>(){

            var post_url = "/Web/Pages/Shop/Shop.php";
            var request_method = "post";
            var form_data = $(Form_AddToCart_<?php echo $item['id'];?>).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url : post_url,
                type: request_method,
                data : form_data
            }).done(function(result){
                $('#navigation').load(document.URL +  ' #navigation');
                $('#shoppingCartModal').load(document.URL +  ' #shoppingCartModal');
                $('.shop_item_<?php echo $item['id'];?>').modal('hide');
                document.getElementById('result-box').innerHTML += '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>Item has been added to Your shopping cart!</div>';
                });

        }
        </script>
```

> This line:

```
$('#shoppingCartModal').load(document.URL +  ' #shoppingCartModal');
```

Comment: You appear to be running raw HTML inside of your PHP function. You'll want to `echo` all of this out, or separate out your presentation from your logic.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Sorry, don't really understand what you mean. Can you please somehow explain it shortly? How I understand at this moment. I need to echo all my html code?

Comment: In your most important code. There is no activity regarding deletion of order (delete_order_). Share your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your delete button's code as below. Explanation of the code is below.
put this script on your page, not the one loaded via AJAX

```
<script>
    function deleteOrder(o) {
        var order_id = $(o).data("order-id");
        var item_id = $(o).data("item-id");
        $.ajax({
           url: "Shop.php?delete_item=true?action=select&id="+item_id+"&order_id="+order_id,
           type: "get",
           success: function(result){
               var item_id = result.item_id; //this should be returned from result
               $('#cart_item_'+result.item_id+').style.display = 'none';
               $('#cart_total').load(document.URL +  ' #cart_total');
               $('#navigation').load(document.URL +  ' #navigation');
           }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and the code for button

```
<button id="delete_order_<?php echo $order['id']; ?>" data-order-id="<?php echo $order['id']; ?>" data-item-id="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" onclick="deleteOrder(this);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
```

**Explanation**

`data-order-id="<?php echo $order['id']; ?>"  data-item-id="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>"` adds the necessary order id and item id attributes to your button so that we can use them in the function `deleteOrder`. `deleteOrder` should be placed on your page, or in one of your javascript files. It doesn't really matter as long it is there when the page is loaded. `onclick="deleteOrder(this);"` will trigger the function on click and will send it's properties of the button as the argument of the function when clicked on.

`var order_id = $(o).data("order-id");` gets the order id, that we set on button so we can use it AJAX request.

if you omit

```
var item_id = result.item_id; //this should be returned from result
$('#cart_item_'+result.item_id+').style.display = 'none';
```

from your ajax, the ajax will be called but it will not properly hide the necessary row. To fix the issue, the file `Shop.php` should return the necessary id in json format such as `echo json_encode(array('item_id' => $_GET['id']));`